# How to create json file in node js

Tags: json, node.js

I work on a site that manage football league, with utilizing angularjs & nodejs without any database...
I treat with teamsInfo.json like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http');

var fs = require('fs');
var teamsInfo = require('./data/teamsInfo.json');

var app = express()
  .use(express.bodyParser())
  .use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/teamsInfo', function  (req, res) {
  res.json(teamsInfo);
});

app.post('/teamsInfo', function  (req, res) {
  teamsInfo.push(req.body);
  fs.writeFile('./data/teamsInfo.json', JSON.stringify(teamsInfo));
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.post('/teamsInfo/:id', function  (req, res) {
  //something
});
```

It works correctly but thats not a point, my problem is when you want to store and show week result to user.
Our result data store like this: `result1.json - result2.json - result3.json` and ...
If i wanna treat with this json's like `teamsInfo.json` I should right many get and post functions to handle request and response. And the point is all of them do the same thing, because the format of result json's are same.

my question is:

1. how can I create json file when user click on nextWeekResult function? (I evalute name by a counter then create it physically in my system)
2. how can I write just one get and post functions that handle all result.json  files?

Thanks.

Comment: The one above is not a *json* find. Do you mean *js*?

Comment: this is my reult.json file, i put the get/post of teamsInfo.json for instance of a normal form of get/post, but what i want is i have many jsons that the name of them is "result1.josn", "result2.josn ,... i dont want to write many get/post for each of them how can i write one get/post that handle all result jsons? (this is my second question)
 [ {
    "team1": {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Wall Breaker"
    },
    "team2": {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Dinner buyers"
    },
    "result": [
      "16",
      "14"
    ],
    "date": "2015-11-14T15:15:25.845Z"
  }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super clear about what your asking, but to dynamically load/save files you can use the id provided to build dynamic filenames to target. An example to dynamically get a file based on id, if you're letting your end user specify the id to use:

```
app.get('/teamsInfo/:id', function(req, res) { 
  // dynamically build file to load based on id
  var filename = util.format('teamsInfo%s', req.params.id);
  var teamInfox = require(util.format('./data/%s.json, filename));
  res.json(teamsInfox);
});
```